# Theme file upload form element

Tags: 8, theming, files

I want to theme all the file upload fields on my site but I don't know how to name the template file.

I want to alter the form-element.html.twig file but as I have multiple file fields I don't think that the best way is to create theme files for each field. So I was thinking to create a theme based on the field type. Is that possible?

I used the hook_theme_suggestions_input_alter.

```
function MY_MODULE_theme_suggestions_input_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (strcmp($element['#type'],'file') == 0) {
    $suggestions[] = 'form-element--file';
  }
}
```

After clearing the caches seems that doesn't work.

Is this the correct way or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Ivan Jaros, you can override input--file.html.twig if you want to use twig templates. Basic input template is as follow:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for an 'input' #type form element.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: A list of HTML attributes for the input element.
 * - children: Optional additional rendered elements.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_input()
 */
#}
<input{{ attributes }} />{{ children }}
```

If you need to add more dynamic variables, you can use **template_preprocess_input()** preprocess function.

Also, you can use **debug: true** under **twig.config** in services.yml. This will help for theme-related development.

**Note: Drupal provides default classes that are from generic to specific to the field. If generic classes helps to theme, I would suggest to avoid all the above.**

Comment: Thank you. That's fine. I already used the classes but what I really want to do is to display the uploaded files below the input field.  Also as I have enabled the multiple upload, I get the label in a summary tag and in the actual label tag, I get the 'Add new file', so I also want to change this. FYI, I display the node edit form in a block.

Comment: I would suggest using theme function to fetch the temporary uploaded files. Save it in a variable. Use the variable in twig template to render the files.

Comment: And when a user uploads a file using javascript to place it in the correct div? Also using this way (which is interesting) I should also hide the other existing rendered files (using css?).